# Change text color of SVG when clicked on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am using d3.js to build a stacked bar graph. I am referring to this graph http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

I have functionality that if you click on any legend that age group population will hide on all states bar. What i want is when I click to hide any age group population from the graph I want to change the text color of that legend in "red" color. Here is my code

```
              legend.append("text")
              .attr("id", "legd-text")
              .attr("x", width-10)
              .attr("y", 40)
              .attr("dy", ".15em")
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
              .on("click", function(){
                   var changeTextColor = document.getElementById('legd-text');
                   changeTextColor.setAttribute("fill", "red");     
              }) 
              .text(function(d) {
                  return d; });
```

But this is not working. Please help me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried using jQuery to do this?

```
$("#legd-text").attr("fill", "red");
```

or try

```
$("#legd-text").css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: Yes I have tried it but I want that specific legend to become red. This is making all the legends red.

Comment: You will need to give it a specific ID tag then, if they all have the same ID of legd-text then it will change all of them.

Comment: you could give it an attribute or a class name and reference it byt that class="changeme" then $(".changeme").attr("fill", "red");

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting all of your legend labels to have the same `id`?  They should all have different `id` values so you can query for them individually.

For your particular case, though, you can maybe take advantage of the fact that the `this` reference inside a d3 event listener function refers to the current DOM node (as with most d3 callbacks):

```
    .on("click", function() {
         d3.select(this).attr("fill", "red");    
    })
```